# jQuery form not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

    var ajax_load = "<img src='load.gif' alt='Loading...' />";

    $('#create').submit(function() {
        $("#result").html(ajax_load);
        $.get("actions/create.php", { url: longform },
            function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            });
        );
    });
</script>
```

But all that happens is the URL in the address bar changes to:

```
http://domain.com/?longform=http://www.google.com/&submit=Submit
```

The form and result div:

```
<form name="create" action="" id="create">
    <input type="text" name="longform" /> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<div id="result">
results go here
</div>
```

Do I need to have the ajax code in the head section? Or does that not matter..

**UPDATE**:

The code on my page now looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

    var ajax_load = "<img src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";

    $('#create').submit(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#result").html(ajax_load);
        $.get("actions/create.php", { url: longform },
            function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            });
        );
    });
</script> 
</head> 

<body> 
<form name="create" action="" id="create"> 
    <input type="text" name="longform" /> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Shorten" /> 
</form> 

<div id="result"> 
123
</div>
```

Still doesnt work. actions/create.php simply echos a foobar string to test it out.

**UPDATE**:

I have also tried this:

```
$('#create').submit(function() {
    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url:    'actions/create.php',
        data:   formdata,
        success: function(responseText){
                $('#result').html(responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

But it also doesnt work.. could something in my htaccess be messing with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it worked once I put all the jQuery BELOW the form and results div.. how tedious.

Comment: that's because the form wasn't part of the DOM when the script executed. You should have wrapped the script as part of the `document.ready` event. `jQuery(function($){/* Your code here */});`

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
function(data){
    $('#result').html(data);
});
```

should be

```
function(data){
    $('#result').html(data);
}
```

and you need to prevent the default behavior of your form submit action (submitting the form via POST):

```
$('#create').submit(function() {
    // ...
    return false;
});
```

You can (additionally) take a look at jQuery's [`.load()`-method](http://api.jquery.com/load), which does exactly what you are doing, but shorter. The whole thing would look like this:

```
$('#create').submit(function() {
    $("#result").load("actions/create.php", { url: longform });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `submit` event doesn't happen **instead** of submitting but **before** it, thus your form submits normally after the JavaScript is executed. You need to cancel the normal submitting by either returning `false`  from the event handler:

```
$('#create').submit(function() {
    $("#result").html(ajax_load);
    $.get("actions/create.php", { url: longform },
        function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
        });
    );
    return false;
});
```

Alternatively you can call `preventDefault`. See http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score -1):

remove the action attribute from the form tag